# how can custom permalink structure use for specify custom post type

Tags: customization, permalinks

generated url some thing like this
http://domain/test/testing-web002/

here test = custom_taxonomy(we can say custom category slug)
and
testing-web002 = custom post slug

its showing 404 error at frontend.

what is issue here and what is its template structure for fetch post at frontend.
please help me.

Comment: How did you created the taxonomy and custom post type ? Any plugin or via code?

Comment: via code 1.) register_post_type, 2.) register_taxonomy used